# Не изменяется текст в TextView

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема: не заменяется текст в TextView (проверял, ID ресурсов не пересекаются):

```
public void updateUserName(TextView textView) {
    String str = textView.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("before_ " + str);
    textView.setText("my_name");
    str = textView.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("after_ " + str);
}
```

Путем вывода текстов в консоль, я выявил, что textView изменяет свое значение (т.е. getText возвращает "my_name"). Однако, в самом приложении изменений не происходит. Быть может, неправильный идентификатор ресурса TextView я передаю?

Я его получаю в LoginActivity в методе onCreate (src_name, src_email и src_avatar объявлены в начале класса LoginActivity как private TextView и private ViewImage):

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view); // получаем ID ресурса
src_name = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_header_username); // получаем ID имени
src_email = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_header_useremail); // получаем ID почты
src_avatar = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_header_useravatar); // получаем ID аватара
```

Затем передаю в функцию создания пользователя (оттуда уже и вызывается первоначальный updateUserName с до сих пор передаваемыми аргументами src_name, src_email и src_avatar).

Comment: Случайно пользователь не в другом потоке создается?

Comment: Простите, а как я это могу выяснить? Могу лишь сказать, что в отдельном классе

Comment: @odosenok а этот метод у вас где?

Comment: Из класса LoginActivity вызывается метод обновления класса, принадлежащий UseProfile

Comment: Если этот метод ходит в базу или в сеть - то скорее всего он выполняется в другом потоке. По коду это видно обычно. Как вариант можете попробовать textView.post(new Runnable(){textView.setText("my_name");})

Comment: Ни в базу, ни в сеть не идет. Дико извиняюсь, что сейчас не могу проверить.

Comment: Нет,  не помог такой метод с Runnable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна из причин такого поведение - попытка изменения интерфейса из другого потока. 
Для корректной работы с некоторыми элементами и обновления содержимого можно использовать следующий код:

```
public  void UpdateUI() {
        try {
            ((Activity) this).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /// code here...
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("UI ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Если метод находится вне класса активити - передавайте так же ссылку и на неё. Ниже код вашей функции с изменениями

```
public void updateUserName(final TextView textView, Activity activity) {
        try {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String str = textView.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("before_ " + str);
                    textView.setText("my_name");
                    str = textView.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("after_ " + str);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("UI ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: К сожалению, таким образом подчеркивается UIContext (Expression expected). Я пробовал менять на свою активность, но все безрезультатно
Или это нужно вставлять в тот класс где хранится мой TextView?

Comment: UIContext - это условное обозначение. Если метод updateUserName находится в коде той активите которую обновляете то напиши просто this или LoginActivity.this

если метод в другом классе то передавайте в месте с ссылкой на textview ещё ссылку на активити. выше привел пример (поправил ответ)